# How to make a primitive point to a reference?

Tags: java, int, primitive

I would like to know why the primitive int didn't change as the size of the array changes. Doesn't the primitive point to the array reference?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

int num = list.size();

list.add("item1");
list.add("item2");

System.out.println(num); //why is the num variable still equals to zero?
```

Comment: I assume this is just for learning purposes but in general you are better off without using temp values especially when they can be easily retrieved (such as by using list.size() )

Answer (score 2):

Primitives *can't* point since they're primitives; they hold a value and that's it. If you want the value to change, you must change it. Consider using an observer type pattern if you want to change the num variable when the List changes, or even better, doing away with num completely and just call `list.size()` when you need its size.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: dang, and I'm a grammar nerd too. Thanks.

Comment: Can a primitive hold an address value?

Comment: @bvj: of course it can, but how would you get the address? and if you did get it, you couldn't use it as an address as you would with C programming without some extra help such as JNI or JNA.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My version of your latest comment is: "Yes, but no, not really".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  ugh... language ambiguity. Yes, was thinking C++.

Comment: I'd tend to put it as "Java doesn't really have the concept of an address value.". It's implemented that way, but the language itself doesn't really have that concept.

Answer (score 1):

A primitive points to an area of memory that holds a static (not to be confused with the `static` keyword) value, they are not able to reference a variable within a class. Essentially when the primitive is changed it now points to a new memory location that has the new number inside of it.

In addition the size variable in the List is also a primitive. That primitive may seem to change but it is only because it is changed each time that something is added or removed from the list.

Comment: Fair enough, I couldn't think of a way of writing an unchanging value that sounded better.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a call to `size()`, you're getting a snapshot of the size of the collection at that instant in time.  You don't get any extra reference to it, since it's just a numerical value.  It can never hold a reference of any kind, it'll always be a raw, numerical value.

The `size()` method has the ability to reference the internal state of the collection, so it's better to use that instead of storing it in another variable.